# Can not get list in a model which I get it AsQuerable in ef?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public int UserId{get;set;}

    public Users User{get;set;}
}
```

I have set the Users to Product's relative:

```
b.HasOne("User").WithMany().HasForeignKey("UserID");
```

When I use `entityframework` to get the list of products.

The User is returned null, why?
There is a value in `User` table and the `UserId` is right in `Product` Table.

```
var list = _context.Products.AsQueryable();
```

the `items` in `list` has the `User=null`.

Comment: Please add the code in which you're trying to get the User with

Comment: @MohamadMousheimish thank you.I have added.

Comment: And can you please add a snapshot to your context? I think it's a DbSet<Product> right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Include the entity you're looking for. For example, let's suppose I have the following context.

**AppDbContext.cs**

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Offer> Offers { get; set; }
}
```

**Notification.cs**

```
public class Notification
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int? OfferId { get; set; }
    public virtual Offer Offer { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to use the `Offer` entity from `Notification`, you need to use the following statement:

```
context.Notifications.Include(n=> n.Offers).ToList();
// Your code goes here
```

In your situation:

```
var list = _context.Products.Include(p=> p.User).AsQueryable();
```

Comment: what about FindAsync? var list=_context.Products.FindAsync(id);

Comment: `FindAsync` will not includeb`User`. The `User` entity will still be returned Null

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly ask to include the users in the returned list.

```
_context.Products.Include(p => p.Users).AsQueryable();
```